# Query Link Table SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am having trouble wrapping my head around a simple query.  I have a `Link` table like this:

```
+----------+----------+
| SourceID | TargetID |
+----------+----------+
| 1        | 2        |
+----------+----------+
| 1        | 3        |
+----------+----------+
| 3        | 4        |
+----------+----------+
| 3        | 5        |
+----------+----------+
```

And a table of `Names`

```
+----------+----------+
| ID       | Name     |
+----------+----------+
| 1        | Mitch    |
+----------+----------+
| 2        | Cheryl   |
+----------+----------+
| 3        | Sue      |
+----------+----------+
| 4        | Harry    |
+----------+----------+
| 5        | Bob      |
+----------+----------+
```

And I desire output like so.  Structured just like the link table, but with the names instead.

```
+------------+------------+
| SourceName | TargetName |
+------------+------------+
| Mitch      | Cheryl     |
+------------+------------+
| Mitch      | Sue        |
+------------+------------+
| Sue        | Harry      |
+------------+------------+
| Sue        | Bob        |
+------------+------------+
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `join` the `names` table twice with different aliases. Change the `join` to `left join` if the `link` table will have id's that are not in `names`.

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/18b8c/4)

```
select t1.name as sourcename, t3.name as targetname
from link t2
join names t1 on t1.id = t2.sourceid
join names t3 on t3.id = t2.targetid
```